# How can I add a route that is "on the link", directly connected to the interface even if the IPs are not the same?

Tags: networking, server, 17.10, netplan

We're working on an Ubuntu 17.10 linux and we would have to use Netplan for network configuration. We have a `/run/systemd/network/*.network` file which fit what we need, but we want to "translate" it in a Netplan config file.

```
[Match]
Name=ens18

[Network]
Address=<guestIP>/32
Gateway=62.210.0.1
DHCP = none
DNS=8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4

[Route]
Destination=62.210.0.1/32
Scope = link
```

We want to transpose this in the `/etc/netplan/*.yaml` file but we don't find how to do those two things:
  - The `scope = link` doesn't seem to have a direct translation in the .yaml file. We're using it because we're working into a VM;
  - The `via` line is required in the .yaml file when configuring route but `0.0.0.0` doesn't work.

With our configuration via the .network file, here is what `route -n` returns:

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         62.210.0.1      0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 ens18
62.210.0.1      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 ens18
```

So how to translate our two problematic lines in the Netplan config file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with netplan 0.34 (now in Ubuntu 18.04), you can add "scope: link" to your route in netplan config, with something like this:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eth0:
      [...]
      gateway4: 62.210.0.1
      routes:
        - to: 62.210.0.1/32
          via: 62.210.0.1
          scope: link
```

Comment: And writing this I realise we have a bug; since netplan currently enforces you have both 'via' and 'to', which is non-sensical in the scope: link case. I've accounted for this in the example, and I think it should work this way.