# Netplan: ipv6 route on link

Tags: networking, netplan

I'm trying to declare a static ipv6 route on the link using netplan (more precisely I'm trying to setup a default gateway whose address is not on my interface subnet)

Basically what I'm trying to do via netplan is:

```
ip -6 a a fd00::1/64 dev eno4
ip -6 r a fd00:1::2/128 dev eno4
```

**Os: Ubuntu 18.04**

**Netplan version: 0.36.3**

The following solution does not work:

```
    eno4:
        addresses:
           - fd00::1/64
        routes:
           -   to: fd00:1::2/128
               via: fd00:1::2
               on-link: true
```

then

```
netplan --debug apply 
journalctl -u systemd-networkd
eno4: Could not set route: No route to host
```

and the route does not show up when listing them

I also tried replacing the on-link:true by scope:link with no more results (not sure what the difference between both is)

I know this question is almost a dupplicate of this one

[How can I add a route that is "on the link", directly connected to the interface even if the IPs are not the same?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/993971/how-can-i-add-a-route-that-is-on-the-link-directly-connected-to-the-interface)

However I found that the accepted answer does not work for me even for ipv4, unless I replace the 'scope: link' with 'on-link: true'

So questions:

- Has anyone managed to make scoped link routes work with netplan + ipv6 ? If so what's wrong in the example above ?
- Can someone explain what the difference is between scope:link and on-link:true ?
- Why is a **'via'** attribute mandatory for an onlink route ?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

It's possible you are being affected by a known bug in the Ubuntu 18.04 version of systemd-networkd, for which a fix is in progress. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/systemd/+bug/1812760