# IPv6 default route NOT being set netplan Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS

Tags: networking, 18.04, netplan, routing, ipv6

Am unable to configure the default route using `netplan` on an Ubuntu 18.04.2 system. The route works when explicit `ip -6 route add ...` commands are issued.

Privacy extensions have been disabled: **/etc/sysctl.d/10-ipv6-privacy.conf**

```
net.ipv6.conf.all.use_tempaddr = 0
net.ipv6.conf.default.use_tempaddr = 0
net.ipv6.conf.ens192.use_tempaddr = 0
```

SLACC and RA have been disabled, IPv4/IPv6 forwarding are one (machine serves as an OpenVPN server)

**/etc/sysctl.d/10-ipv6-router.conf**

```
net.ipv6.conf.default.autoconf = 0
net.ipv6.conf.all.accept_ra = 0

net.ipv6.conf.all.proxy_ndp = 1
```

**/etc/sysctl.conf**

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
...
net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding=1
```

**/etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml**

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    ens18:
      dhcp4: no
      addresses:
        - a.b.c.d/24
      gateway4: a.b.c.e

      dhcp6: no
      accept-ra: no
      addresses:
        - "2001:0db8:0004:4a1a::dead:beef/64"
      gateway6: "2001:0db8:0004::0001"

    ens19:
      dhcp6: no
      accept-ra: no
      addresses:
        - "2001:0db8:0004:4a1a::dead:dead/64"
      gateway6: "2001:0db8:0004::0001"
```

This assigns the addresses to the interface as shown below:

```
$ ip -6 addr show

2: ens18: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 state UP qlen 1000
    inet6 2001:0db8:0004:4a1a::dead:beef/64 scope global 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::abcd:efff:fea3:2a03/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: ens19: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 state UP qlen 1000
    inet6 2001:0db8:0004:4a1a::dead:dead/64 scope global 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::defc:deff:fe98:7c74/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

The routes using `ip -6 route show`

```
2001:0db8:0004:4a1a::/64 dev ens19 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
2001:0db8:0004:4a1a::/64 dev ens18 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium

fe80::/64 dev ens19 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
fe80::/64 dev ens18 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
```

There is **no** default route configured and pinging external sites does NOT work:

```
$ ping -6 -c3 ipv6.google.com
connect: Network is unreachable
```

Running the following two commands:

```
$ sudo ip -6 route add 2001:0db8:0004::0001 dev ens18 metric 1
$ sudo ip -6 route add default via 2001:0db8:0004::0001 dev ens18 metric 1
```

Now running `ip -6 route` shows:

```
2001:0db8:4::1 dev ens18 metric 1 pref medium

2001:0db8:4:4a1a::/64 dev ens19 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
2001:0db8:4:4a1a::/64 dev ens18 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium

fe80::/64 dev ens19 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
fe80::/64 dev ens18 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium

default via 2001:0db8:4::1 dev ens18 metric 1 pref medium
```

A default route is **now** configured and pinging external sites **works**:

```
$ ping -6 -c3 ipv6.google.com
PING ipv6.google.com(ord38s18-in-x0e.1e100.net (2607:f8b0:4009:804::200e)) 56 data bytes
64 bytes from ord38s18-in-x0e.1e100.net (2607:f8b0:4009:804::200e): icmp_seq=1 ttl=56 time=23.2 ms
64 bytes from ord38s18-in-x0e.1e100.net (2607:f8b0:4009:804::200e): icmp_seq=2 ttl=56 time=23.2 ms
64 bytes from ord38s18-in-x0e.1e100.net (2607:f8b0:4009:804::200e): icmp_seq=3 ttl=56 time=23.2 ms

--- ipv6.google.com ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2002ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 23.274/23.283/23.293/0.176 ms
```

**So, what is wrong with the netplan configuration? Why are the default IPv6 routes not being configured?**

**Edited after making changes suggested by @slangasek:**

```
 ethernets:
    ens18:
     ...

      dhcp6: no
      accept-ra: no
      addresses:
        - "2001:0db8:0004:4a1a::dead:beef/64"

      routes:
        - to: "::/0"
          via: "2001:0db8:0004::1"
          metric: 1
          on-link: true
```

However, this does **not** work. I get messages like `ens18: Could not set route: No route to host` in the journal logs.

From the answer at https://askubuntu.com/a/1014683, I added the additional route to the router using `scope: link`:

```
  routes:
    - to: "2001:0db8:0004::1/128"
      via: "2001:0db8:0004::1"
      metric: 1
      scope: link
    - to: "::/0"
      via: "2001:0db8:0004::1"
      metric: 1
      on-link: true
```

But, still **not** working!

Comment: Please add DNS nameservers as outlined here: `cat /usr/share/doc/netplan/examples/static.yaml` and then try again.

Comment: Pray what has DNS servers got to do with default routing. DNS and routing works at very-very different levels in the IP hierarchy. Is `netplan` so terribly broken?

Answer (score 5):

Your configuration shows you have a local network of 2001:0db8:0004:4a1a::/64 but you are trying to configure a gateway of 2001:0db8:0004::0001 which is not part of that network.  So networkd refuses to add a default route via a router that you to not have a route to.

Your manual configuration with `ip route` also reflects this: you are first adding a route for the router's address, declaring that it is locally connected to your Ethernet, and afterwards setting the default route.

So you must do the equivalent with netplan, which is to declare two entries in routes:, one that is `scope: link` and one that sets `on-link: true`:

```
  addresses:
    - "2001:0db8:0004:4a1a::dead:dead/64"
  routes:
    - to: "2001:0db8:0004::0001/128"
      scope: link
    - to: "::/0"
      via: "2001:0db8:0004::0001"
      on-link: true
```

Comment: As an aside, I don't understand why you would have a network like this.  This contradicts all the basic principles of routed networks to have your gateway not have a local network address.

Comment: not my decision to make. It is the service provider who have made that decision. However, my network is part of the /48 routed by the router - so this should not be considered way off!

Comment: Still does not work. I am not getting the route configured. In the `journalctl` output, I get:
`Jun 03 11:32:34 jwaala systemd-networkd[5917]: ens19: Could not set route: No route to host`
`Jun 03 11:32:34 jwaala systemd-networkd[5917]: ens19: Configured`
`Jun 03 11:32:34 jwaala systemd-networkd[5917]: ens18: Could not set route: No route to host`
`Jun 03 11:32:34 jwaala systemd-networkd[5917]: ens18: Configured`

Comment: @slagasek: Please see edited question above and let me know what you think? Any idea where to get the fikle generated by `netplan generate`?

Comment: Have given up on this netplan thing and moved to ifup as given in (https://askubuntu.com/a/1052023/)

Comment: are you sure that /64 is even the correct netmask for your local network, and that it shouldn't be /48?

Comment: Yes. Everything works with `ifupdown`. Either `netplan` is broken or poorly documented, especially for IPv6.

Comment: I have reproduced this locally; the issue is that you have an invalid 'via' in your first route.  I have updated my answer to show the correct syntax, which works for me here.

Comment: Also my question about the correct netmask for your network was not because I believed the configuration could not be made to work as described, but because it's bad network design on the part of your provider if you must configure your network this way, and it's possible /48 is the correct netmask for the provider's network.

Answer (score 1):

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    ens19:
      dhcp6: no
      accept-ra: no
      addresses: ["2001:0db8:0004:4a1a::dead:dead/64"]
      gateway6: "2001:0db8:0004::0001"
      routes:
         - to: "2001:0db8:0004::0001/128"
           scope: link
```

This works for me as of this writing on Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS (using different netblocks but tested)

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this issue. The actual cause is written right in /etc/sysctl.conf

```
# Uncomment the next line to enable packet forwarding for IPv6
#  Enabling this option disables Stateless Address Autoconfiguration
#  based on Router Advertisements for this host
#net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding=1
```

When IPv6 forwarding is disabled, the host will not listen to router advertisements, which is how the default route is usually determined. Therefore, you have to manually add the default route (and DNS servers and anything else you were getting out of the RA) or, set the `accept_ra` kernel option to 2, which overrides the behaviour.

[See this blog article](https://strugglers.net/%7Eandy/blog/2011/09/04/linux-ipv6-router-advertisements-and-forwarding/) for some more info.